# SSMS Syntax Highlighter Support for Lead and Lag

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, syntax-highlighting, ssms-2014

I'm currently using SQL Server Management Studio 2014, and even though [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125(v=sql.110).aspx) and [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx) have both been part of SQL Server since 2012, they still do not (by default) have any syntax highlighting (see below):

[image]

Is there any way to add these functions to the syntax highlighter in SSMS so that they show up in pink?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems like there is no way to edit the list of keywords that SSMS will highlight for you.

There was a similar question over at [ask.sqlservercentral](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/27662/highlighting-all-keywords.html), where they list 2 alternatives, one of which is an alternate IDE that does not list SQL Server 2012 or 2014 as being compatible. This leaves us with:

Use an extension (I havent found any in a quick google search) or develop one yourself

Alternatively, you could use an editor such as Notepad++ that supports having custom keyword lists and delimiters, though in my opinion its a poor man's replacement.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was afraid of...  I was hoping that it would be configurable somehow, but I'm also seeing the same results you mentioned.

Comment: I tried poking around in some of the XML and config files in the MS SQL sub-directories with no success. One of them looked promising, but didn't affect the highlighting.